# comparing entered date with database date except year

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `months` -

```
create table months (mid int(10), month varchar(12));
```

in `mid` column i have given `1` to `12` numbers and months `January` to `December`

and other table `allocate` , i have 33 colums

```
mid - reference key for **months** table
product_id - comes from url
```

columns `day1` to `day31` to store the days for every month on the particular product according to product_id.

User enters the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. If i exclude year it will become mm-dd format, this i want to compare with database date. But there it is day1 to day31 for days. How can i compare these two dates

I am not getting how this can be done

Comment: What's the reason you have 31 day columns instead of just one `day` field?  Better yet, why not utilize a `DATE` data type?

Comment: actually, one of my customer has a criteria to allocate each day with different customer once in a while (resort management firm), for that it is like that. if i use date datatype for `day1` to `day31` colums, it takes complete `yyyy-mm-dd` format, where as i want to store only number of days in the column. it they enter 0 for `feb 14th` in database, when user enters the same date , he should get a message that there is not availabilty ...

Comment: none of those requirements suggests that you should not use a date value - and certainly none suggest that you must have the denormalized structure thatyou are describing.

Comment: Even if it's just a `Day` field of type `INTEGER` it would make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest altering your table structure to make use of date datatypes, as well as normalizing it (ie not having 31 columns to represent day of month).

If you want to extract the Month, 1-12 from a date field, use `MONTH()`, likewise `DAY()` for day.

Otherwise you'll be breaking the user supplied date apart and have to use dynamic queries to point to the intended field.

I can't tell from the question what you need exactly, and how the data is being used, but I see mention of Product_ID.  So perhaps you need something like:

```
YourTable (ProductID, Date, Value)
```

The year can always be the same if it's irrelevant in your data.  Instead of having 31 day fields you'd just have multiple rows, ie:

```
ProductID Date         Value
1         19000501     5
1         19000502     9
1         19000503     4
```

If you add some context on what you're storing and how you're using it I'm sure we can come up with a table structure that makes sense.

Comment: I have altered data type integer to date but how i can normalizing it. i have to have 31 columns for each day as they enter data for each day

Comment: and also, after changing datatype to `date`, i inserted integer value `2` for `day1` but it is not taking, it just takes 0000-00-00

Comment: Instead of columns of days, you'll have multiple rows with different values in the `day` field, ie if there's a record for every day of a month for a given product_ID, then you'd have as many rows as there are days in that month.

Comment: It might not make sense for you to use the `DATE` data type, but it's hard to tell from your question what the best layout would be.